# English acronyms in a Greek document

Tags: babel, acronyms

I am trying to make a acronyms list in a Greek document, but the english word appears with greek letters..My preamble is the following..

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{acronym}

\begin{document} 
\chapter*{Ακρωνύμια} 

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Ακρωνύμια} 

%place for all the ackronyms

\begin{acronym}[BisGMA]

\setlength{\itemsep}{-\parsep}

\acro{BisGMA}[\textit{BisGMA}]{Δικλυδικός μεθακρυλικός εστέρας της δισφαινόλης Α} 

\end{acronym}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are two possible solutions:

## `pdflatex`

You need to load some additional packages:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
```

Then inside the second field of `\newacro`, add `\selectlanguage{english}` to typeset that word in Latin script.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\begin{document} 
\chapter*{Ακρωνύμια}   
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Ακρωνύμια} 

%place for all the ackronyms    
\begin{acronym}[BisGMA]

\setlength{\itemsep}{-\parsep}

\acro{BisGMA}[\selectlanguage{english}\textit{BisGMA}]{Δικλυδικός μεθακρυλικός εστέρας της δισφαινόλης Α} 

\end{acronym}   

\acl{BisGMA}
\end{document}
```

---

## `xelatex`

If you're willing to switch to this engine, you can choose any font you have on your OS that supports both scripts. I chose a random one, but you can change it to a different one.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Script=Greek]{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{greek}

\begin{document} 
\chapter*{Ακρωνύμια} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Ακρωνύμια} 

%place for all the ackronyms
\begin{acronym}[BisGMA]
\setlength{\itemsep}{-\parsep}

\acro{BisGMA}[\textit{BisGMA}]{Δικλυδικός μεθακρυλικός εστέρας της δισφαινόλης Α} 

\end{acronym}

\acl{BisGMA}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have loaded babel but didn't write it on the question.. I was putting \selectlanguage{english} in the wrong place, thank you for noticing..

Comment: @PetrosMourouzis You're welcome! The command is `\acro{<label>}{<acronym>}{<full acronym>}` so the first one is just the command you pass to Latex, the second one is what gets shown in the PDF.